# Equivalence of topological continuity definitions

Tags: general-topology

I'm looking at two definitions of continuity:

1. Let there be a function, $f: X \to Y$. Let $x \in X$. Then $f$ being $\textbf{continuous at $x$}$ means that for any neighborhood of $f(x)$, $V \subseteq Y$, there exists a neighborhood of $x$, $U \subseteq X$, such that $f[U] \subseteq V$.
2. Let there be a function, $f: X \to Y$. Let $x \in X$. Then $f$ being $\textbf{continuous at $x$}$ means that for any open set containing $f(x)$, $V \subseteq Y$, there exists an open set containing $x$, $U \subseteq X$, such that $f[U] \subseteq V$.

Do I have them both right? If so, could someone please show that they're equivalent? It's clear that $(1)$ implies $(2)$. How do I show $(1)$, though? Is it even true?

Comment: What is the difference between a neighborhood and an open set?

Comment: A neighborhood of a point is a set containing an open set of the point. I.e. $x \in O \subseteq N$. A neighborhood itself need not be open.

Comment: Yes they are equivalent. You are trying to show (2) implies (1)? Note that any open set containing x is a neighborhood of x, and every neighborhod contains an open neighborhood.

Comment: No.  In both, U subset V is wrong.  U subset X is correct. For the most part the notion of neighborhood is a historical hangover of little worth.  Orginally topology was pioneered with nhoods, only later to be refined to open sets.  The 2 is actually the definition of continuous at x.  A worthwhile problem is to show ta

Comment: A worth while problem is to show:  f is continuous at x for all x in X iff for all open V subset Y, f ^-1(V) is open within X.  The latter is usual definition of continuity.

Comment: Neither of them is right but I think that is due to a typo. You should have $U\subset X$ not $U\subset V.$

Comment: @user254665 Good find, thanks.

Comment: This is a topological generalization of the "$\epsilon$-$\delta$" def'n of continuity of real functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's formulate it more correctly: let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a function.
The two definitions are:

1. $f$ is continuous at $x \in X$, if for every neighbourhood $V \subseteq Y$ of $f(x)$ there exists a neighbourhood $U \subseteq X$ of $x$ such that $f[U] \subseteq V$.
2. $f$ is continuous at $x \in X$, if for every open set $V \subseteq Y$ such that $f(x) \in V$ there exists an open set $U \subseteq X$ with $x \in U$ such that $f[U] \subseteq V$.

By definition $A$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ in any space iff there is en open set $O$ such that $x \in O \subseteq A$. In particular an open set is a neighbourhood of each of its points.

1 implies 2 because if $f(x) \in V$ and $V$ is open it is a neighbourhood of $f(x)$ and 1 applies to get a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, and thus an open set $U'$ with $x \in U' \subseteq U$. Now we can use this $U'$ as the required open set for 2, as $f[U'] \subseteq f[U] \subseteq V$.

2 implies 1, because of $V$ is a neighbourhood of $f(x)$ we have an open set $V'$ of $Y$ such that $f(x) \in V' \subseteq V$. Then definition 2 gives us an open set $U$ with $x \in U$ and $f[U] \subseteq V' \subseteq V$ and we note that $U$ is already as required as $U$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, being open.

So their equivalence is quite trivial from the definition of neighbourhood.

Now it's easily shown that "$f$ continuous at all $x \in X$" is equivalent to "$f^{-1}[O]$ is open in $X$ for all open $O \subseteq Y$". This is easiest from definition 2,as it is already in terms of open sets.

Comment: Thanks for your response! By the way, I've played around with how I formulated my definitions in the title (including fixing two straight-up errors). They're still not quite the same as yours, but are they alright?

Comment: @JohnDoeVsJoeSchmoe They're essentially the same, yes.